# wget embedded in php to download image

Tags: php, image, system, exec, wget

From the command line, `wget http://mydomain.com/image.jpg` successfully downloads the image.

The image file size is 7KB.

When I embed this code into `exec()`, `system()` or `passthru()`, such as

```
exec('wget http://mydomain.com/image.jpg');
```

or the same with `system()` or `passthru()`

The image gets created but only has 255 bytes...

Can anybody tell me why this happens?

Comment: Are you using this from the command line or via a web page? Is there any output, if so, what is it?

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of that shorted file to see if it's a jpg? It could be a 404 or 401 type error page instead of .jpg data.

Answer (score 3):

I would try using the quiet (-q) and specifying an output file (-O). It is possible its continual status updates are causing an issue.

Here is an example of grabbing google's logo that is working for me.

`<? system('wget -q http://www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif -O test2.gif'); ?>`

wget v1.12

php v5.3.1

Comment: system ('wget -q `http://mydomain.com/image.jpg` -o image.jpg'); creates the image but now it is 0 bytes

Comment: -O, not -o. Uppercase. Lowercase -o is for logfile.

Comment: I updated the orig answer with a specific example. Give that one a try. It is working fine for me.

Comment: I tried your example and it worked fine. I don't understand why my example returns an image file with 0 bytes. Here is my command: system('wget -q http://images.guitarcenter.com/products/full/SKB/632866258731107602.jpg -O christian_wget.jpg'); Can you please try it? Thanks! :)

Comment: OK. I got it. with php 5.2.9, I get a 0-byte image. With php 5.3.1, it works perfectly well... I get a 7.03KB image. Now that is weird... Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, that works for me. Downloads a 7K image. It even works for me without the -q and -O options. What wget version are you using?

Comment: I am  not sure how to find out the wget version. Any idea where I could look?

Comment: `wget --version`. Just saw your other comment. Guess its a bug in the older php version...

Comment: wget version 1.10.2. It works with php 5.3.1 but not with php 5.2.9... I am not sure why...